# Teradata stored procedure result output

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

How I can print `var2`?

```sql
REPLACE PROCEDURE Name(out var2, in var1)
---some code goes here
BEGIN
      TRANSACTION;

      SET var2= var1+ 5;

end;

REPLACE PROCEDURE Name(out var2, 5)
```

Comment: Your example procedure has issues, but to retrieve (and display/print) a procedure OUT parameter value depends on your client or driver. In general you have to "bind" a local variable to hold the result. In the case of SQL Assistant, you simply provide a dummy variable name in the argument list `CALL Name(outval,5)`